# How to create this specific if/if excel formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I basically have three tables that I want to test through an IF/ else IF formula in Excel.  The first table corresponds to whether I would take a bet given a set of parameters (in short, this is a n row x 1 column table filled with 1s and 0s). The second table is whether I would win the bet (this is also nx1 and filled with 1s and 0s).  The third column is the profit I would make if I did take the bet AND if I won.

So far the pseudo-code I have is:

```
if (would bet=1) AND (would win=1), are...
    TRUE: display profits
    FALSE: if (would bet=1) and (would win = 0) are...
        TRUE: -1 (for losing $1 betting)
        FALSE: 0 (for not betting)
```

I have my tables set up as follows:

Profits table: column A
Would bet table: Column B
Would win table: Column C

so in cell D1, I entered:

```
=IF(AND(B1=1, C1=1), A1, IF(AND(B1=1, C1=0), -1, 0))
```

but for some reason, I'm not getting any -1's though there are supposed to be some.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your logic a bit to the following pseudo code:

```
IF (would bet)
   IF (would win)
        DISPLAY PROFITS
   ELSE
        DISPLAY -1 // loser!   
ELSE 
   DISPLAY 0 // didn't play
```

With that simplified logic, I think you can go with this as your formula:

```
=IF(B1=1, IF(C1=1, A1, -1), 0)
```

Where B1 = would bet, C1 = would win, A1 = profits

Answer (score 0):

As a small aside/contribution, this is a fairly short formula, but I often split complex IFs in several columns to do the debugging easier , or,  for really complex (or maybe overcomplicated :))  decisions I create a custom formula and code the logic as in your pseudocode pretty much. that has a performance penalty in big tables and requires saving it as a macro enabled  xlsm which requires users to enable the content, but it improves auditability massively, reduces the risk of error and let to comment the code for the future. I would recommend (if not yet familiar) that you give it a go to have another tool in your belt. You can google around on how to create a custom formula)
Cheers